# String.find returns true always (C++)

Tags: c++, boolean

Im trying to have the boolean found_word to return true if it finds the word/character and false if it doesn't, but it returns true ALWAYS, no matter what I write in the text. The loop itself works, already tried that. IOStream and string are included.

```
while(timestorun){
    found_word = text.find("khgdawjugfdjhawbdjkhsadgawkdsa");

    if(found_word){
        cout << "FOUND!!!" << endl;
    }
    else if(!found_word){
        cout << "Found problem!!!!!"<< endl;
    }
    timestorun--;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `else {` instead of `else if(!found_word){`. This will not change how your code works but it is a little cleaner.

Comment: I cant, because in the real code there are quite some more if/elses

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're supposed to compare with `npos`. `find` doesn't return a boolean value.

```
found_word = text.find("khgdawjugfdjhawbdjkhsadgawkdsa") != std::string::npos;
```

`0`, which is `false`, would only be returned if the substring was found at index `0`.

Also, your second condition is redundant - if `found_word` is `false`, I personally guarantee `!found_word` will be `true`.

Comment: +1. And in particular, `string::npos` is `(size_t)-1`, which is true in a boolean context.

Answer (score 2):

it should be something more like this:

```
int main ()
{
    int found = text.find("some text");
    if (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        //do stuff if word is there
    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff when word isnt there
    }
}
```

text.find should return a -1 if the word isnt there, otherwise it returns the position in string that you found it

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, too used to System::String (-1 replaces std::string::npos in the Windows System C++ version of String)