# how to find a substring or string literal

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to write a code that will search userInput for the word "darn" and if it is found, print out "Censored". if it is not found, it will just print out the userInput. It works in some cases, but not others. If the userInput is "That darn cat!", it will print out "Censored". However, if the userInput is "Dang, that was scary!", it also prints out "Censored". I am trying to use find() to search for the string literal "darn " (the space is because it should be able to determine between the word "darn" and words like "darning". I am not worrying about punctuation after "darn"). However, it seems as though find() is not doing what I would like. Is there another way I could search for a string literal? I tried using substr() but I couldn't figure out what the index and the len should be.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string userInput;

   userInput = "That darn cat.";

   if (userInput.find("darn ") > 0){
      cout << "Censored" << endl;
   }
   else {
      cout << userInput << endl;
   } //userText.substr(0, 7)

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LONG, is that a `std::string` function?

Comment: `find` returns `std::string::npos` when it can't find a substring, not 0. 0 indicates that the substring it located at the beginning of the string. Your condition `userInput.find("darn ") > 0` is essentially only `false` if `userInput` begins with `"darn "`.

Comment: Hint: search for "darn" not "darn " and check adjacent symbols then.

Comment: Adding on to @FrançoisAndrieux 's comment, note that `std::string::npos` is implemented as `(std::size_t)-1`, i.e. `INT_MAX`, which will always be greater than 0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183784/string-find-returns-true-always-c

Comment: I am working out of an online program for my coding class and we havent learned that yet so I know it has to be possible using either lenght(), empty(), find(), or substr().

Comment: my thought process behind checking it being greater than 0, is that I thought that find() returns a number or an index, and if it could find the number (it would be greater than 0) and the if statement would compile. if it could not find the string, it would not be greater than 0, because it does not exist and it would go to the else statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is your condition.  `std::string::find` returns a object of `std::string::size_type` which is an unsigned integer type.  That means it can never be less than 0 which means

```
if (userInput.find("darn ") > 0)
```

will always be `true` unless `userInput` starts with `"darn "`.  Because of this if `find` doesn't find anything then it returns `std::string::npos`.  What you need to do is compare against that like

```
if (userInput.find("darn ") != std::string::npos)
```

---

Do note that `userInput.find("darn ")` will not work in all cases.  If `userInput` is just `"darn"` or `"Darn"` then it won't match. The space needs to be handled as a separate element. For example:

```
std::string::size_type position = userInput.find("darn");
if (position != std::string::npos) {
    // now you can check which character is at userInput[position + 4]
}
```

Comment: The condition will evaluate to false when the match is found in the first character, which is why the results seem sporadic to the OP

Answer (score 0):

`std::search` and `std::string::replace` were made for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string userInput;

    userInput = "That darn cat is a varmint.";

    static const string bad_words [] = {
            "darn",
            "varmint"
    };

    for(auto&& bad : bad_words)
    {
        const auto size = distance(bad.begin(), bad.end());
        auto i = userInput.begin();
        while ((i = std::search(i, userInput.end(), bad.begin(), bad.end())) != userInput.end())
        {
            // modify this part to allow more or fewer leading letters from the offending words
            constexpr std::size_t leading_letters = 1;

            // never allow the whole word to appear - hide at least the last letter
            auto leading = std::min(leading_letters, std::size_t(size - 1));

            auto replacement = std::string(i, i + leading) + std::string(size - leading, '*');
            userInput.replace(i, i + size, replacement.begin(), replacement.end());
            i += size;
        }
    }

    cout << userInput << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
That d*** cat is a v******.
```